# I'm trying to make a tag where it downloads a file but it downloads the link to the file, not the actual file

Tags: html, angular, typescript, download

I want to make an `<a>` tag where it the click function will execute a function called downloadFile() in the typescript file so it will download a log file. instead of downloading the log file, it downloads the link to the log file which does work, but I want to have the download display the actual log information.

```
downloadFile() {
    const blob = new Blob(['blablabla.log'], {type: 'text/log'});
    const dataURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
      return;
    }
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = dataURL;
    link.download = 'export file.log';
    link.click();
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(dataURL);
    }, 100);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not the way to download a file on click from a Blob. Here's how you should proceed:

1. Create some blob with some file content and some type
2. Create an URL object. You'll pass this value to an `<a>` `href` attribute
3. Create an `<a>` and set its `download` attribute to the desired file name
4. Make the element non-visible, add it to the DOM, and click on it

Example below:

```js
const downloadFile = () => {
  const blob = new Blob(
    ['Some file content'],
    {type:'text/log'}
  );
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href=url;
  a.download='some-file-name.log';
  a.style.display='none';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

```html
<a onclick="downloadFile()">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: is there a method to where instead of having the some file content can i have the link of the content instead and convert it because the content is very long

Comment: In this case simply write `<a href="path-to-your-file" download="file-name">`. Check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) for usage in case you're facing a bug.

Comment: it doesn't download the file